# How to get Matplotlib events to communicate with each other?

Tags: matplotlib, event-handling

I'm using Matplotlib to build an interactive drawing tool but I am having trouble with concurrent events. Specifically I'd like to use the keyboard and mouse together, but I'm not sure how to pass information between event handlers. How can I get the mouse event handler to know that a key is currently being pressed? I am trying to use a global variable, as below, but it's not working.

Any help appreciated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

SHIFT_PRESSED = False

def on_key_press(event):
    if event.key == 'shift':
        SHIFT_PRESSED = True    

def on_key_release(event):
    if event.key == 'shift':
        SHIFT_PRESSED = False    

def on_click(event):
    print(SHIFT_PRESSED) # never prints True

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_click)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', on_key_press)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_release_event', on_key_release)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I think you're going to have to mark `SHIFT_PRESSED` as a global variable

Comment: @PaulH Wow, it was as simple as that. I can update `ax` without declaring `ax` as a global variable, though. I wonder what accounts for the difference.